# How to prevent Google from indexing non-domain URL of website?

Tags: google, domains, search-engine-indexing

My webhost gives you two URLs for your website:

1. the URL on your shared server, which is something like `usr283725992783.webhost.com`
   and
2. your domain URL, which is `www.example.com`

Google is indexing both of these URLs, but obviously I only want `www.example.com` to be indexed.

I can't add "nofollow" tags to `usr283725992783.webhost.com` because that URL serves the same files as `www.example.com`.

How can I only make Google not follow `usr283725992783.webhost.com` and keep following `www.example.com`?

Comment: Why do you care if the search results end up at your website?  I would love to have doubled search results for an important site.

Comment: Many reasons. One, I don't want anyone seeing any more "private" server info than they need to. Two, I use things in PHP such as $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and I don't want to write the code to check for two possibilities (the domain and the server url). And three, it just looks bad having some cryptic URL in the search results. I also don't believe duplicate content on different domains is good for your search rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you will most probably have duplicate content issues and thus indexing issues for your site.

To avoid duplicate content issues with search engines, you can add a `rel="canonical"` tag ([how to use it on Google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)) in all your pages to specify the right version of pages is the one from `www.example.com`.

Comment: Zistoloen, sorry, I don't think you understood my question. `www.example.com` is the same as `usr283725992783.webhost.com`. They both load the exact same files, except `www.example.com` is simple a domain pointed to `usr283725992783.webhost.com`. If I changed the .htaccess file, it will affect both `usr283725992783.webhost.com` and `www.example.com` because it is the same files.

Comment: @Gavin: you're right, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need to do. In PHP I'll check which site is being loaded and display the canonical tag if it's `usr283725992783.webhost.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I thing going for 301 redirect using .htaccess will make google not follow this link.Or you can use robots.txt.

Comment: Read the first comment of the OP under my answer and please update your answer.